# Getting userprofileupdate timestamp in apex

Tags: chatter, profile, user

I want to get time when user profile image gets updated. How can i get that in apex?

Answer (score 0):

Write a trigger on User object to verify "FullPhotoUrl" field on User object.
Whenever a user updates a profile pic, then this field will be updated and then based on that timestamp you can store the details on a field or use it as needed.

Alternate Way -

after discussion over comments as trigger does not fire on this field, there can be an alterante lengthy way

Create a custom field to store Photo URL(__c), no create a workflow for everytime record is created or edited criteria, then populate this custom field using field update. Write a trigger on this custom field now.

I checked the portion where Custom field can be populated with a Photo URL in a field update task.

Hope it helps.

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: Did you try to write that trigger? Problem is that it doesn't work

Comment: Can you paste your trigger code?

Comment: when you change profile picture, trigger doesn't fire at all:

`trigger UserProfilePictureChange on User (before update,after update) {`
`system.assert(false,'It should fail, but it does not'');`
`for(User u : Trigger.new){`
`if (u.FullPhotoUrl != Trigger.oldMap.get(u.Id).FullPhotoUrl){`
`//do magic here `
`}`
`}`
`}`

Comment: tried that, it was weird.Last modified changed though

Comment: added alteranative way in answer. Check if it works.Thanks

Comment: @KaushikRay Issue with updating photoURL custom field is we do not get fullphotoURL field in workflow fieldupdate its accessible only via apex then how we will be updating custom field.

Comment: Which field did you use in field update? it tells me `Error: Field FullPhotoUrl does not exist. Check spelling.`

Comment: I added PhotoURL only and used normal "Add Field" biutton to check same

Comment: @KaushikRay But what you are saving in PhotoURL field and how?

Comment: I will give you a snapshot in some time..!!!